# I'm having problems with Epic games and unreal engine. specifically with my projects not showing up

Tags: unreal-engine5

Hey I am brand new to unreal engine 5 and unreal in general. I would love to start making games so right now I am following a tutorial on yt. it asked us to download a character for our game and when i tried I couldnt find my project. I can open the game project through files but i still cant add the assets from the market place.[image: Here are the screenshots]

Comment: Hi, since this isn't a programming question - you're unlikely to get an answer here. But you could try the unreal forum, or game dev stack exchange.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried launching the engine and then opening the project? and for assets you can just import them from the content browser